# Which versions of iOS and Android webviews already support ES6 modules?

Tags: cordova, webview, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, phonegap

I've been wondering which os/webview versions already support ES6 modules (import/export feature) natively without having to transpile to ES5 via webpack/babel.

Please note that I'm asking about native webview support (for Cordova/PhoneGap) and ***not*** for mobile browser support such as Safari or Chrome.

I heard that iOS 10.3 does support it but I'm not sure, also I'm absolutely clueless regarding the current state on Android.

Couldn't find a clear answer googling around. Does someone have exact information on this or at least a link to a resource to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I found out, the current state as of May 2017 is like this:

---

**iOS**

UIWebView: No support

WKWebView:

- CORS error when served from file:///
- 403 error when served via local http server plugin in Cordova
- Serving from /external/ works

---

**Android**

No support in webview at all

---

Browsers are a bit better and catch up on support, see https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: On Android, one can develop with the WebView from Chrome 61 Beta. It is scheduled to shift from Beta to Stable in September 2017.  To use it now, follow the instructions at https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview/android-webview-beta

Comment: WebView in Android 8.1 is implemented by Chrome and it comes with Chrome 61 which supports ES modules https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/nic61#modules. It's said that actually true starting from Android 7.0 (http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/20/google-explains-chrome-will-become-webview-android-7-0/). So all you need there is to upgrade Crome to the latest version.