# ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: Set is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On some browsers only i get the

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Set is not defined.

It is reactjs app created with create-react-app.

Why do i still get the error?
How do i use polyfill?
Does not reactjs use polyfill by default?

webpack.config.prod.js

```
entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
```

polyfills.js

```
'use strict';

if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
  // Rejection tracking prevents a common issue where React gets into an
  // inconsistent state due to an error, but it gets swallowed by a Promise,
  // and the user has no idea what causes React's erratic future behavior.
  require('promise/lib/rejection-tracking').enable();
  window.Promise = require('promise/lib/es6-extensions.js');
}

// fetch() polyfill for making API calls.
require('whatwg-fetch');

// Object.assign() is commonly used with React.
// It will use the native implementation if it's present and isn't buggy.
Object.assign = require('object-assign');

// In tests, polyfill requestAnimationFrame since jsdom doesn't provide it yet.
// We don't polyfill it in the browser--this is user's responsibility.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  require('raf').polyfill(global);
}
```

Comment: It seems we need to use `import 'babel-polyfill'` on our reacttjs components which needs polyfill. But why should we? Cant the babel loader handle it?

Comment: I see this error on some Chrome/Android browsers even though I have Set polyfilled with `https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=...,Set,Map"></script>`

Answer (score 9):

No sure whether anyone found the right solution. However for older browser especially on Android Kitkat 4.4 browsers/webview this problem is very evident. Please use the following link for the solution

https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

If you are using ReactJS 16 then first include the babel-polyfill

- npm install --save babel-polyfill

Open your index.js and import the babel-polyfill

- import 'babel-polyfill'

Create a build and deploy. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue while working on my React project.
So I just install **babel-polyfill** package.
Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue [with older WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890272/which-versions-of-ios-and-android-webviews-already-support-es6-modules) that doesn't support `ES6`.
I faced this issue on Genymotion (Android API 21), where it somehow did not work even after updating Chrome.
But it worked on physical device.